# Select values from column with more than one values in another cumulus

Tags: sql

I have table X
with 2 columns : ID , name

I need to select only the names with more than 1 ID (and count how much ID those name has)

table X

```
|namme|ID  |
------------
|A    |1   |
------------
|A    |2   |
------------
|B    |1   |
------------
|C    |1   |
------------
|C    |4   |
------------
|C    |7   |
------------
```

from the table bellow the answer will be like:

```
|namme|ID Count|
----------------
|A    |2       |   
----------------
|C    |3       |   
----------------
```

name A has 2 IDs

name C has 3 IDs

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT(*) etc

Comment: can you elaborate more please ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, like:

```
   SELECT Name
    ,COUNT(ID)
FROM Xtable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function `count()`

```
 select name,count(*) as cnt from table  group by name
 having count(*)>1
```